# phpmyadmin EXCEPT SELECT is not usable

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, subquery, sqlexception

I am trying to use `EXCEPT` when getting data from 2 tables, but I can not use `EXCEPT SELECT`.

Phpmyadmin does not recognize `EXCEPT` and does not allow me to use the 2nd `SELECT`.

Is there other way i can check for same entries on the tables?

EDIT:
if t1 has rows:

```
id1-name1, id3-name3
```

and t2 has:

```
id1-name1, id3-name3, id4-name4
```

then i would get a table with id4-name4 only (talking about rows)

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not support the `EXCEPT` syntax.

A typical solution is to use `NOT EXISTS` instead. Assuming that both tables have a structure like `(col1, col2, col3)`, you would go:

```
select t2.*
from t2
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from t1
    where t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 = t1.col2 and t2.col3 = t1.col3
)
```

This returns rows from `t2` where no row exists in `t1` with the same tuple of values in the three columns.

Comment: Got one more related question, how do i go about to edit or select things from this newly made table?